# Script On Click Css Display Property Changes Not Working Normally Asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, internet-explorer, google-maps

i am trying to display google map on click java script changes its display property and shows google map. Its not working on IE 8 and working fine on other browsers if i do not use CSS its working fine too on IE

my code is as under

```
   <div class="getDirectionsBtnMain">
        <a href="#" id="new-yorkiframeNav" onclick="toggle_visibility('new-yorkiframe');">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="new-yorkiframe" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(5, 72, 65); width: 950px; border: 10px solid rgb(5, 72, 65);" class="tab-pane vcard">
        <iframe frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 379px;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
            src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=+40+Wall+Street,+11th+Floor+New+York,+NY+10005&aq=&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=39.320439,86.572266&t=m&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=40+Wall+St,+New+York,+10005&iwloc=A&output=embed">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

script is as,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);

            alert(e.style.display);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
            e.style.display = 'none';
        else
            e.style.display = 'block';
        if (e.style.display != 'block' && e.style.display != 'none')
            e.style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
```

In CSS i am using this property,

```
#new-yorkiframe{display:none;}
```

First of all its not showing its Display property it is showing "null" that i alert in script it is behaving same in other browser too but after changing its property in script it show maps in other browser except IE

but if i change its css property to,

```
new-yorkiframe{display:none;}
```

its click button shows and hide map on ie as well as on other browser.

What should i do that i want to hide map first time page load ??

Hopes for you Cooperation

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hello. Try to do: href="javascript:toggle_visibility('new-yorkiframe'); return false;" and do not bind onclick function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you keep the "`<script>..you code..</script>`" just before closing the html tag

Comment: i keep script after opening html tag

Comment: move the script exactly before `</html>`

Comment: i move it just above the html closing tag but problem still there

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle_visibility(id) {
            var ele = document.getElementById(id);
            if (ele.style.display == 'block')
              ele.style.display = 'none';
            else
              ele.style.display = 'block';
      }
      window.onload = toggle_visibility('new-yorkiframe');
</script>
```

Comment: its behaving same not working on IE 8 showing white screen in plave of map

Comment: if i use visibility in place of display it works fine but they both are not same we have to use display